# jQuery access input field by name[value][id]

Tags: jquery, drupal, cck, checkbox, inputbox

I have some HTML code like this:

```
<input id="fieldname-1" name="field_name[value][1]" value="1" type="checkbox" />
<input id="fieldname-2" name="field_name[value][2]" value="2" type="checkbox" />
<input id="fieldname-3" name="field_name[value][3]" value="3" type="checkbox" />
```

I want to access this with jQuery like:

```
$('input[field_name]').change( function() { dosomething(); });
```

i can not add a class field to do this by calling `$('.classname')` because it is rendered by the cck module of Drupal and i don't want to add this to the theme layer.

The best thing would be to let my module add a class for every field. but a quicker solution would be to know how to access these fields by jQuery

Comment: why not accessing by id?

Comment: Because with id you can only access one field.
I want my jquery to run on multiple fields ( forgot to say that in my question )
Also when i add fields i have to rewrite the jQuery code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [the attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to do an exact match on the `name` attribute.

```
$('input[name="field_name[value][2]"]').change(func...
```

Or if you wanted *all* the `<input>` elements that start with `field_name`, you'd use [the attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```
$('input[name^=field_name]').change(func...
```

This will select all `<input>` elements where the `name` attribute starts with `field_name`.

Additionally, you can use `:checkbox` in the selector instead of `input` if they're all checkboxes.

Also, you could use the same approach but with the ID attribute if you wanted.

```
$('input[id^=fieldname]').change(func...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need a fuzzy selector: [name^=value]
Something like this might suffice:

```
$('[name^=field_name]').each(function(index,element){
  $(element).change(function(){})
})
```